# Transform each user_id group to a feature vector

Tags: r

I am having a table `user_aisles` which is a data frame containing `user_id` grouped by `user_aisles` and `n` which is the number of items bought by a user in an aisle.

```
kable( head( summarize(user_aisles, n=n()) , 9) )
```

gives

```
| user_id| aisle_id|  n|
|-------:|--------:|--:|
|       1|        2|  8|
|       1|        3| 12|
|       1|        4|  5|
|       2|        1|  1|
|       2|        3|  6|
|       2|       14|  1|
|       2|       17|  2|
|       2|       20|  1|
|       2|       21|  5|
```

I would like to transform this into feature vectors for *each* user id. Such a feature vector should be `nrow(aisles)` dimensional.

So each `user_id` gets a corresponding feature vector. Feature vector for user 1 could (based on the data) look like

```
1: [0, 8, 12, 5, 0, .., 0]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
groups <- split(df, df$user_id)
lapply(groups, function(x) rep(x$aisle_id, x$n))
```

You can use `split` to group your users and then the `rep` function to expand the aisle ids.

Comment: Hm. No that's not what I need. `x$aisle_id` is supposed to be the _index_ in each feature vector. I am not sure why you're just repeating the value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data in a dataframe called `data` you can use `tidyr`'s `complete` function:

```
library(tidyverse)    
data %>% complete(user_id, aisle_id = 1:21, fill = list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 42 × 3
   user_id aisle_id     n
     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1        1        1     0
2        1        2     8
3        1        3    12
4        1        4     5
5        1        5     0
6        1        6     0
7        1        7     0
8        1        8     0
9        1        9     0
10       1       10     0
# ... with 32 more rows
```

Here I'm assuming there are 21 possible aisle ids based on the largest value in your data.

If you want a row for each consumer you can use `spread`:

```
data %>% 
complete(user_id, aisle_id = 1:21, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
mutate(aisle_id = paste0("aisle_", formatC(aisle_id, width = 2, flag = 0))) %>% spread(aisle_id, n)

    # A tibble: 2 × 22
  user_id aisle_01 aisle_02 aisle_03 aisle_04 aisle_05 aisle_06 aisle_07 aisle_08 aisle_09 aisle_10 aisle_11 aisle_12
*   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1       1        0        8       12        5        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
2       2        1        0        6        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
# ... with 9 more variables: aisle_13 <dbl>, aisle_14 <dbl>, aisle_15 <dbl>, aisle_16 <dbl>, aisle_17 <dbl>, aisle_18 <dbl>,
#   aisle_19 <dbl>, aisle_20 <dbl>, aisle_21 <dbl>
```